Unable to upgrade spring boot version of JBPM project
Currently we are using kie-server-spring-boot-starter version 7.74.1.Final and Spring Boot version 2.5.9.  Spring boot versions below 3.x versions has security vulnerabilities so we are trying to upgrade spring boot version to 3.2.2.   After upgrading spring boot version to 3.2.2, the Spring Boot application is not getting started. Getting below error in startup.
application start up logs:
2024-10-26T16:59:02.505+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.domain.rdm.RdmJbpmAppApplication   : Starting JbpmAppApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 12492
2024-10-26T16:59:02.510+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.domain.rdm.RdmJbpmAppApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-10-26T16:59:03.765+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-10-26T16:59:03.815+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 32 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-10-26T16:59:04.504+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 7777 (http)
2024-10-26T16:59:04.517+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-10-26T16:59:04.517+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-10-26T16:59:04.653+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-10-26T16:59:04.657+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2071 ms
2024-10-26T16:59:04.957+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-10-26T16:59:05.040+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
2024-10-26T16:59:05.088+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-10-26T16:59:05.244+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-10-26T16:59:05.578+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6a6e9289
2024-10-26T16:59:05.583+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-10-26T16:59:05.748+05:30  WARN 12492 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: OracleDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-10-26T16:59:05.963+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-10-26T16:59:06.369+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JTA platform [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform]
2024-10-26T16:59:06.438+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-10-26T16:59:06.456+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] c.c.rdm.utils.GlobalVariablesUtils       : JBPM Profile :- null
2024-10-26T16:59:06.456+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] c.c.rdm.utils.GlobalVariablesUtils       : JBPM Application Properties file name :- application.yml
2024-10-26T16:59:06.559+05:30  WARN 12492 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-10-26T16:59:06.878+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@11ad327f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4b808427, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@33622388, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@426bf2f2, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@167f9043, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@48928b57, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@229fe7ab, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6e664075, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1c571162, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6771fc29, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@9a74a93, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@21f0cc97]
2024-10-26T16:59:06.897+05:30  WARN 12492 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userGroupCallback' defined in class path resource [com/cotiviti/rdm/security/RdmWebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'userGroupCallback' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.kie.internal.identity.IdentityProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-10-26T16:59:06.901+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-10-26T16:59:06.905+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-10-26T16:59:06.946+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-10-26T16:59:06.949+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-10-26T16:59:06.961+05:30  INFO 12492 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-10-26T16:59:06.986+05:30 ERROR 12492 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method userGroupCallback in com.domain.rdm.security.WebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.kie.internal.identity.IdentityProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.kie.internal.identity.IdentityProvider' in your configuration.


below is the class where above IdentityProvider class being used.
public class RdmWebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /*
     * @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     * 
     * http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
     * .antMatchers("/rest/*").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and()
     * .headers().frameOptions().disable();
     * 
     * }
     */
    
      @Bean
      public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
          httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                  .requestMatchers("/rest/*").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and()
                  .headers().frameOptions().disable();
          return httpSecurity.build();
      }

    @Bean(name = "userGroupCallback")
    public UserGroupCallback userGroupCallback(IdentityProvider identityProvider)
            throws IOException {
        return new RdmCustomUserGroupCallbackImpl();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        //corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.DELETE.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name()));
        corsConfiguration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}

Am I missing any configurations required for spring boot 3 for JBPM?

Looking at it on mvnrepository, it seems like that version requires Spring Boot 2.x so you might be best off creating an issue in that library.
